# Как в React вывести массив картинок?

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs

В data приходит массив картинок, все ок, но не понимаю, как его отрендерить. Или это невозможно в функциональном компоненте? Я сильно новичок в этом. Используется стек Mern + multer.

```
function SubletCard(props) {        
    const [files, setFile] = useState([{data: [] }])
    const tempArr = [];    
    const handleImageUpload = e => {
        [...e.target.files].forEach(file => {
            tempArr.push(
                file
            );
        });
        setFile(tempArr)
    };

    async function submitHandler(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        setIsEditing(false)
        props.setSublets(prev =>
        prev.map(function (sublet) {
            if (sublet._id == props.id) {
            return { ...sublet, city: draftCity, rooms: draftRooms }
            }
            return sublet
        })
        )
        const data = new FormData()
        if (files) {
            files.forEach(file => {
                data.append("photos", file);
            });
        }

        const newPhoto = await Axios.post("/update-sublet", data, { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } })
        

        if (newPhoto.data) {
            props.setSublets(prev => {
                return prev.map(function (sublet) {
                    if (sublet._id == props.id) {
                        return { ...sublet, photo: newPhoto.data }
                    }
                return sublet
                })
            })
        } 

    return (
         <img src={props.photo ? `/uploaded-photos/${props.photo}` : "img/fallback.png"} className="card-img-top" alt={`${props.rooms} named ${props.city}`} />

       )
}
```

Рендер app

```
function App() {
const [sublets, setSublets] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    async function go() {
        const response = await Axios.get('/api/Sublets');
        setSublets(response.data);
    }
    go()
}, [])
return (
    <div className='container'>
        <p><a href='/'>&laquo; Back to the homepage</a></p>
        <CreateNewForm setSublets={setSublets} />
        <div className='sublet-grid'>
            {sublets.map(function(sublet) {
                return <SubletCard key={sublet._id} city={sublet.city} rooms={sublet.rooms} 
                photo={sublet.photo} id={sublet._id} setSublets={setSublets} />
            })}
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}
const root = createRoot(document.querySelector('#app'))
root.render(<App />)
```

Comment: В каком компоненте вам надо отрендерить массив картинок?

Comment: в первом, функция submitHandler

Comment: Это функция ничего не рендерит и как я понимаю вызывается при каком то событии(клик наверное). Дополните ваш вопрос кодом рендера, где должен появиться массив картинок. И по функции - вы хотите отрендерить данные, которые пришли в `newPhoto.data`

Comment: Ниже есть функция рендера  `function App()` . Да, я хочу отрендерить эти данные. Но не очень понимаю, где мне делать перебор пришедшего массива

Comment: ну как я понимаю вам нужно перебор картинок делать в вашем компаненте `SubletCard`. Вы же туда передаете в пропсах массив `photo={sublet.photo}`

Comment: `App()` и `submitHandler` исходя из кода вообще не связаны между собой... Разве что `submitHandler` передает значения в `sublets`, которые вы и так рендерите. `submitHandler` нигде не вызывается. Детализируйте, пожалуйста, что именно не получается и где. Возможно у вас не рендерится компонент `SubletCard`? тогда нужен и его код.

Comment: `submitHandler` по факту передает данные и все. Он вызывается при `form.onsubmit` . Компонент `SubletCard` это первый компонент, который я привела. Если я верно понимаю, перебор надо делать в `App`, в части `{sublets.map(function(sublet) {
                return <SubletCard key={sublet._id} city={sublet.city} rooms={sublet.rooms} 
                photo={sublet.photo} id={sublet._id} setSublets={setSublets} />
            })}`. Не очень правда понимаю как

Comment: `sublets.map` это и есть перебор. Но всех значений которые вам прилетат от `api`. Покажите данные что приходят от апи `response.data`

Comment: Получаю я это `[{"_id":"634001b50da78fb03f3ad311","city":"","rooms":"","photo":["1665139125149.jpg"]},
 {"_id":"6340043266e84c3d836d72ba","city":"","rooms":"","photo":["1665139762346.jpg","1665139762356.jpg"]},
 {"_id":"634021bcfff528fd485a707f","city":"Haifa","rooms":"1","photo":["1665147324549.jpg","1665147324563.jpg"]}]`

Comment: @KrisK попробуйте как-то так `{props.photo.map((photo,index) => (
      <img key={index} src={photo ? `/uploaded-photos/${props.photo}` : "img/fallback.png"} className="card-img-top" alt={`${props.rooms} named ${props.city}`} />
    ))}` в `SubletCard`

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin
Да, это сработало! Огромнейшее спасибо. Я пыталась сделать что-то подобное, но неверно...

Comment: @KrisK написал в виде ответа) если остались еще что-то непонятно , спрашивайте)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

с вашими данными от бэка

```
[{"_id":"634001b50da78fb03f3ad311","city":"","rooms":"","photo":["1665139125149.jpg"]},  {"_id":"6340043266e84c3d836d72ba","city":"","rooms":"","photo":["1665139762346.jpg","1665139762356.jpg"]},  {"_id":"634021bcfff528fd485a707f","city":"Haifa","rooms":"1","photo":["1665147324549.jpg","1665147324563.jpg"]}]
```

первый рендер идет в компаненте `app`

```
    {sublets.map(function(sublet) {
        return <SubletCard key={sublet._id} city={sublet.city} rooms={sublet.rooms} 
        photo={sublet.photo} id={sublet._id} setSublets={setSublets} />
    })}
```

Тут вы перебираете все значения пришедшиее от бэка. Для каждой позиции. Т.к. в каждой позиции у вас может быть массив с изображениями, вам надо перебрать их и в компоненте `SubletCard`.

```
{props.photo.map((photo,index) => (       
    <img key={index} src={photo ? /uploaded-photos/${props.photo}` : "img/fallback.png"} className="card-img-top" alt={${props.rooms} named ${props.city}} /> )
)}
```